# Java swing application doesnt start

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to write an calculator to view the average grade, but it doesn't start.
It's written with java swing as you can see, help would be appreciated.

The main class:

```
    package me.imfrozen;

public class TheMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FrameA();

    }

}
```

FrameA:

```
package me.imfrozen;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameA extends JFrame {
    static JSpinner sa6;
    static JSpinner sa7;
    static JSpinner sa8;
    static JSpinner sa1;
    static JSpinner sa2;
    static JSpinner sa3;
    static JSpinner sa4;
    static JSpinner sa5;

    static JSpinner ex2;
    static JSpinner ex3;
    static JSpinner ex7;
    static JSpinner ex8;
    static JSpinner ex5;
    static JSpinner ex4;
    static JSpinner ex6;
    static JSpinner ex1;

    static JSpinner af2;
    static JSpinner af4;
    static JSpinner af6;
    static JSpinner af8;
    static JSpinner af3;
    static JSpinner af1;
    static JSpinner af5;
    static JSpinner af7;

    static JLabel lblNewLabel;
    static JLabel label;

    public FrameA() {
        setTitle("Notenrechner");
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(FrameA.class.getResource("/me/imfrozen/icon.png")));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 400);

        JLabel lblSchulaufgaben = new JLabel("Schulaufgaben");
        lblSchulaufgaben.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JLabel lblExen = new JLabel("Stegreifaufgaben");
        lblExen.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JLabel lblAbfragen = new JLabel("Abfragen");
        lblAbfragen.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JSpinner sa5 = new JSpinner();
        sa5.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa6 = new JSpinner();
        sa6.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa7 = new JSpinner();
        sa7.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa8 = new JSpinner();
        sa8.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa1 = new JSpinner();
        sa1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa2 = new JSpinner();
        sa2.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa3 = new JSpinner();
        sa3.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        sa4 = new JSpinner();
        sa4.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        sa4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        ex2 = new JSpinner();

        ex2.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex3 = new JSpinner();


        ex3.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex7 = new JSpinner();


        ex7.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex8 = new JSpinner();


        ex8.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex5 = new JSpinner();


        ex5.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex4 = new JSpinner();


        ex4.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex6 = new JSpinner();


        ex6.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        ex1 = new JSpinner();


        ex1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        ex1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af2 = new JSpinner();


        af2.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af4 = new JSpinner();


        af4.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af6 = new JSpinner();


        af6.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af8 = new JSpinner();


        af8.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af3 = new JSpinner();


        af3.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af1 = new JSpinner();


        af1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        af5 = new JSpinner();


        af5.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        af7 = new JSpinner();
        af7.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 6, 1));
        af7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Dein Notendurchschnitt:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        label = new JLabel("" + rechner.note);          
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));





        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(37)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblSchulaufgaben)
                            .addGap(33)
                            .addComponent(lblExen)
                            .addGap(36)
                            .addComponent(lblAbfragen))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(sa1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(sa5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(63)
                            .addComponent(ex2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(ex5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(38)
                            .addComponent(af1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(af2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(sa2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(sa6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(63)
                            .addComponent(ex3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(ex4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(38)
                            .addComponent(af3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(af4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(sa3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(10)
                                    .addComponent(sa7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(sa4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(sa8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(63)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(ex7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(ex6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(ex8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(ex1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(38)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(af5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(10)
                                    .addComponent(af6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(label)
                                        .addComponent(af7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(af8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblSchulaufgaben, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblExen, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblAbfragen, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(sa1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(sa5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ex2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ex5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(af1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(af2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(sa2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(sa6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ex3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ex4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(af3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(af4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(sa3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(sa7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(ex7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(ex6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(af5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(af6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(sa4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(sa8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(af7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(af8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(ex1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(ex8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                        .addComponent(label))
                    .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);

    }
}
```

rechner (german for calculator):

```
    package me.imfrozen;

public class rechner {
    public static int note = 1;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    public static double sa_ges = 0;

    int sa1 = (Integer) FrameA.sa1.getValue();
    int sa2 = (Integer) FrameA.sa2.getValue();
    int sa3 = (Integer) FrameA.sa3.getValue();
    int sa4 = (Integer) FrameA.sa4.getValue();
    int sa5 = (Integer) FrameA.sa5.getValue();
    int sa6 = (Integer) FrameA.sa6.getValue();
    int sa7 = (Integer) FrameA.sa7.getValue();
    int sa8 = (Integer) FrameA.sa8.getValue();

    int ex1 = (Integer) FrameA.ex1.getValue();
    int ex2 = (Integer) FrameA.ex2.getValue();
    int ex3 = (Integer) FrameA.ex3.getValue();
    int ex4 = (Integer) FrameA.ex4.getValue();
    int ex5 = (Integer) FrameA.ex5.getValue();
    int ex6 = (Integer) FrameA.ex6.getValue();
    int ex7 = (Integer) FrameA.ex7.getValue();
    int ex8 = (Integer) FrameA.ex8.getValue();

    int af1 = (Integer) FrameA.af1.getValue();
    int af2 = (Integer) FrameA.af2.getValue();
    int af3 = (Integer) FrameA.af3.getValue();
    int af4 = (Integer) FrameA.af4.getValue();
    int af5 = (Integer) FrameA.af5.getValue();
    int af6 = (Integer) FrameA.af6.getValue();
    int af7 = (Integer) FrameA.af7.getValue();
    int af8 = (Integer) FrameA.af8.getValue();


    int sa = 0, ex = 0, af = 0, exaf = 0;

    {
    //SCHULAUFGABEN
    if (sa1 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa2 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa3 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa4 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa5 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa6 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa7 >= 1){
        a++;
    }
    if (sa8 >= 1){
        a++;
    }

    //EXEN
    if (ex1 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex2 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex3 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex4 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex5 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex6 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex7 >= 1){
        b++;
    }
    if (ex8 >= 1){
        b++;
    }

    //ABFRAGEN
    if (af1 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af2 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af3 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af4 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af5 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af6 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af7 >= 1){
        c++;
    }
    if (af8 >= 1){
        c++;
    }

    //AUSRECHNEN
    sa = sa1+sa2+sa3+sa4+sa5+sa6+sa7+sa8;
    ex = (ex1+ex2+ex3+ex4+ex5+ex6+ex7+ex8) / b;
    af = (af1+af2+af3+af4+af5+af6+af7+af8) / c;
    exaf = ex + af;
    note = (sa + exaf) / a++ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the codeline: setVisible(true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the line `setVisible(true);` in your FrameA code, without it, your code won't be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
...
FrameA frame = new FrameA();
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You will probably want to set a minimum size for your Frame before you add all your components.